# How to run .x86_64 file on ubuntu 16.04 by terminal?

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

I created unity game , builded it for linux and it gives me **some.x86_64** file. I have remote server running on 16.04(x64)Ubuntu and I can only control it by terminal.I exported all unity game files by using filezilla. How can I run it using terminal ?

Comment: Please look at the below post, https://askubuntu.com/questions/223228/how-do-i-run-a-game-with-a-x86-extension

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for late answer, cd to the folder of your game, then just run this:

```
./some.x86_64
```

that should work, if not do this:

```
chmod +x some.x86_64
```

Comment: lol i forgot to add the code box, thx for changing it for me